# For Hbase, is there a function like EXPLAIN in MySQL?

Tags: sql, hbase

Please bear with me with my lack of knowledge on the following technologies.

We made a bunch of queries (60k queries) that used to take 45 min to complete.  Now, it's taking 3 hrs 20 min for about the same amount.  The person who coded it isn't here anymore so we don't fully know what might be happening.

The lead on my team asked me to see if there's a command like EXPLAIN in SQL to see how hbase is going thru the regions when searching for the rowkey.  I tried to google for it but it doesn't look like there is.  Is there some command in Hbase that's similar to EXPLAIN in SQL?

In case it helps with the question, we are storing time-series data.  The format of the rowkey is:

```
hashOfName_elementName_epochtime
```

We think Hbase should know which regions to avoid from the time and elementName we query for and thus not take this long to query but we're not sure.  Hopefully this command exists so we can see how Hbase is querying so we know whether we need to re-design the schema or redo the rowkey or that it's the amt of data currently stored that's affecting the speed.

Update: We query a time range for a list of elements.  Data is saved once a minute for elements in hbase.  When we do a scan, we can scan for 1 hr or 1 day.
I can see from debug msgs that when we scan, we scan for that block of time.

```
e.g. hash_elementName_timestamp.  timestamp is a 10 digit epoch time
hash = murmur3_128 hash function of the element name
154_eee_0000000000
154_eee_0000000060
154_eee_0000000120
...
..
154_eee_0000003600

167_aaa_0000000000
167_aaa_0000000060
...
...
167_aaa_0000003600
```

Here's a code snippet from our scan method:

```
public Map<String,String> scan(String name, String columnFamilyName, String columnName, long start, long end,
boolean reversed, int limit) throws IOException {

Map<String,String> m = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

Table table = null;
ResultScanner scanner = null;

try {

    String hash = makeHash(name,fType.getNumberOfRegion());
    String key = hash + "_" + name +"_";

    Scan scan;
    if (reversed) {
        //swap the start and end keys when reversed
        scan = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes(key + end),Bytes.toBytes(key + start));
        scan.setReversed(true);
    } else {
        scan = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes(key + start),Bytes.toBytes(key + end));
    }
    scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamilyName), Bytes.toBytes(columnName));
    table =  fCconnection.getTable(fTablename);
    scanner = table.getScanner(scan);

    int count = 0;
    for (Result result = scanner.next(); result != null; result = scanner.next()) {
        //if a limit was set, then only scan until we hit the limit
        if (limit > 0 && count > limit) {
            break;
        }

        m.put(Bytes.toString(result.getRow()), Bytes.toString((result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamilyName), Bytes.toBytes(columnName)))));
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: There is no `explain` in hbase according to my limited knowledge ..  Cassandra which is also `Wide Column Store` has this feature: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2

Answer (score 0):

Well HBase is not SQL. So you do not have the explain. In your case, you need to look into the way the queries are behaving and start tuning. I know its a very high level statement.

You mentioned that you have queries. How are you performing them? Please add details - for more information

Comment: i've edited the question.  Hopefully that gives more info on how we're querying.  I will also try to put a code snippet too after I read the code some more